# Pass query string param into a request call is not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to get the json response for this [product url][1]
using this python script. I looked through the site query parameters and added the Network tab from the dev tools.

I used a similar approach [here][2] to fetch the json response of the query, but when I tried with the code below, it produced an error. Here is the code:

```
def getIndividualItemData():
    print("fetching ")

    
    api_url =  'https://www.walmart.com/product/electrode/api/wpa'
    params = {
        
       
        'el': 'sponsored-container-middle-2',
        'type': 'product',
        'min': '3',
        'max': '15',
        'placementId': '480x345_B-C-OG_TI_2-15_HL-BOTTOM-NY',
        'platform': 'mobile',
        'bucketId':"",
        'bnd': 'Omid Scobie', 
        'moduleLocation': 'bottom',
        'zipCode': '19146',
        'isZipLocated': 'true',
        'sMode': '0',
        'pageType': 'item',
        'vtc': 'QrqzIuiG6-yciq_CD4uAJg',
        'uid': 'daa00990-dab1-4257-9705-3d4a31be8aee',
        'rviItems': '915257222', 
        'itemsAddedToCart': '0',
        'viewportHeight': '616',
        'viewportWidth': '150',
        'userLoggedIn': 'false',
        'showBrand': 'false',
        'itemsList':"" ,
        'pageId': '915257222',
        'keyword': 'Finding Freedom Harry and Meghan and the Making of a Modern Royal Family Hardcover',
        'taxonomy': '3920_5196470_2244664',
        'persistControls': 'true',
        'isTwoDayDeliveryTextEnabled': 'true',
        'mloc': 'bottom',
        'module': 'wpa'

    }


    try:

         try:
            data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()

         except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

i keep getting this error print out

> Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

What is causing the error and how can I fetch the product json response?

I tried a .text print out, and it only show very little data
[1]: https://www.walmart.com/ip/2-Pack-Maxwell-House-Original-Roast-Medium-Ground-Coffee-Caffeinated-42-5-oz-Canister/915257222
[2]: [Python : how to set parameters for python request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993790/python-how-to-set-parameters-for-python-request)

Comment: What status code do you get from the `requests.get`?

Comment: Remove `.json()`  from `data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()` and check the response status code. Also try adding custom headers (at least a useragent).

Comment: @Sayse repsonse from the request call is  <Response [200]>

Comment: When I issue the request I get back an HTML page whose title is **Verify your identity**.

Comment: How can I get around that

Comment: @Booboo and also a recaptcha `Help us keep your account safe by clicking on the checkbox below`

Do you have any param in there which connects to your account? uid, maybe?

I don't have the documentation for the api, but that would be my next step to look at if I were you

Comment: @NationBoneless Why are you asking me?

Comment: @Booboo I didn't intend to, sorry. Sorry this formatting is a bit weird, as all new lines are cut. I wanted to add to your observation with my comment. And additionally ask the OP (as he will get notified anyway), if he had any params or api-docs to look at